# Counting ways to partition a set into fixed number of subsets

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Suppose we have a finite set $S$ of cardinality $n$. In how many ways can we partition it into $k$-many non empty subsets?

Example: There is precisely one way to partition such a set into $n$-many subsets.
and there is one way to partition into a single (sub)set.

Comment: [This other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650791/number-of-partitions-of-an-n-element-set-into-k-classes) is closely related.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you want is the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). A Stirling number of the second kind counts the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ objects into $k$ non-empty subsets. It is usually denoted by $\left\{ n \atop k \right\}$.

See the Wikipedia article for methods to compute such numbers.