# Number of partitions of an $n$-element set into $k$ classes

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

A *partition* of a set $S$ is formed by disjoint, nonempty subsets of $S$ whose union is $S$. For example, $\{\{1,3,5\},\{2\},\{4,6\}\}$ is a partition of the set $T=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ consisting of subsets $\{1,3,5\},\{2\}$ and $\{4,6\}$. However, $\{\{1,2,3,5\},\{3,4,6\}\}$ is not partition of $T$.
If there are $k$ nonempty subsets in a partition, then it is called a partition into $k$ classes. Let $S_k^n$ stand for the number of different partitions of a set with $n$ elements into $k$ classes.

1. Find $S_2^n$.
2. Show that $S_k^{n+1}=S_{k-1}^n+kS_k^n$.

--

**My work:**
From the definition of $S$, $S_2^n=2^n$. I think I am wrong somewhere, because when I put this formula into the second part to prove, I get,
$$k^{n+1}=(k-1)^n+k \cdot k^n.$$
Please tell me where I am wrong. I think this problem cannot be solved by star-and-bar method as that method finds value for $k$ but does not prove it. Please help!

Comment: After your acceptance I had a second look. In your comment on my question you asked whether $S_{2}^{n}=2^{n}-2$ was correct, and I said 'yes'. But it is not.
The correct answer is $S_{2}^{n}=2^{n-1}-1$ i.e. half of it. By counting
the number of non-empty subsets that have non-empty complements you
count every partition twice. I will also put that in the answer I
gave you.

Comment: Can you please explain when we are double counting?

Comment: If every set $A$ with $A\neq \emptyset$ and $A^c\neq \emptyset$ is sent to partition $P=\{A,A^c\}$ then two sets are sent to the same partition: $A$ and $A^c$. This shows that the number of these sets is twice the number of partitions. Do you understand now? Just try it out on some simple cases (3 or 4 elements) and it becomes more easy to see.

Comment: Yes...I actually understand it now very clearly!

Comment: Though not a duplicate, but this question is closely related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541790/counting-ways-to-partition-a-set-into-fixed-number-of-subsets).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**on(i):**

$2^n$ gives you the number of *all* subsets of $S$, but you are looking for the number of subsets that are not empty and have no empty complement. Their total number is $2^n-2$. Note that a nonempty subset $A$ having a non-empy complement $A^c$ corresponds with partion $P=\{A,A^c\}$. However, $A^c$ corresponds with that partition too. So counting these sets gives twice the number of partitions. This amounts in: $$S_n^2=2^{n-1}-1$$
**addendum on (ii)**

Start with a set $S$ having $n$ elements. Now form $S'=S\cup\left\{ x\right\} $
where $x\notin S$. Partitions of $S'$ in $k$ classes can be made in two
ways:

1) Let $\left\{ x\right\} $ be one of the classes. If $P$ is a partition
of $S$ in $k-1$ classes then $P'=P\cup\left\{ \left\{ x\right\} \right\} $
is a partition of $S'$ in $k$ classes. Here there are $S_{k-1}^{n}$ possibilities.

2) Let $\left\{ x\right\} $ be *not* one of the classes. For every partition of $S$ in $k$ classes we can put $x$ in
one of these classes wich will induce a partition of $S'$ in $k$
classes. There are $S_{k}^{n}$ such partitions and for $x$ there
are $k$ candidates so there are $kS_{k}^{n}$ possibilities.

Comment: My logic was:There are $n$ elements and $2$ subsets. So,each element belongs to either first set or the second set. So,$2^n$

Comment: Was the logic wrong?

Comment: Logic is okay, but then the possibility that all elements belong to the first set is included. And also the possibility that all elements belong to the second set. In these cases there is no partition in $2$ disjoint nonempty sets, since one of them is empty.

Comment: so,we can subtract the $2$ cases, so the answer is $2^n-2$. Now, is the logic okay?

Comment: Yes. That is the right answer.

Comment: But, what to do in the second part?

Comment: Haven't thought about that yet (and don't allow manipulation :-)). Maybe something will show up in an addendum, but no promises.

Comment: See my addendum.

Comment: You do not actually try to solve the problem but produce a logic for the proof. Neat! Good one!

Comment: Thank you for the nice solution

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

We can prove $S^n_2 = 2^{n-1} -1$ using Mathematical induction.

${\bf Base\ case} :\ n=1$

Clearly $S^1_2 = 0$ as number of classes need to be 2 but elements in set is 1.

${\bf Inductive\ step}:$ Assuming statement is true for $n=k$, now

Let $a_{k+1}$ is the new element that is added to set of size $k$ to create a new set of size $k+1$.

We can divide $k+1$ elements into 2 parts in two ways

1. $a_{k+1} \cup \{a_1,a_2,...,a_k\}$
2. appending $a_{k+1}$ to either of the 2 classes that we get from each $S^k_2$ partition.

In other words,

$S^{k+1}_2 = 1 + 2S^k_2$

But $S^k_2 = 2^{k-1}-1$

$\implies S^{k+1}_2 = 1 +2(2^{k-1}-1)$

$\implies S^{k+1}_2 = 2^{k}-1$

So, statement is true for $k+1$ and hence true for all natural numbers.

Answer (score -1):

$$S_0^{n}=1,S_1^{n}=n$$
$$S_k^{n+1}=S_{k-1}^n+kS_k^n,k>1$$
for $k=2$ we get that
$$S_2^{n}=S_{1}^{n-1}+2S_2^{n-1}=n+2S_2^{n-1}$$
Solution for last recurrence is not correct because $S_2^{n}\neq2^n$

Comment: The subscript $k$ in $S_k^n$ denotes the number of *classes* in the partition, so $S_1^n$ would be 1, not $n$ (only one way to put all $n$ things into one class).