# Easy way to count number of surjections?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we want the number of surjections $[k]\to[n]$.

Dualizing, the number of injections $[n]\to [k]$ is, I think, just $\frac{k!}{(k-n)!}$. Doesn't this mean the number of surjections in the opposite direction is the same?

Comment: The 'easy' way to count number of surjections would be using the Inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: The expression you have for the number of injections doesn't appear to be right.

Comment: @user84413 maybe $\frac{k!}{(k-n)!}$?

Comment: Right, assuming $k\ge n$.

Answer (score 2):

Every function with domain $A$ induces a partition of $A$. If the range has $n$ elements, then you want to count how many partition into exactly $n$ parts there are, then multiply that by $n!$ as the number of ways to enumerate these parts.

The number of partitions of $[k]$ into $n$ parts is given by [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) (see also [Counting ways to partition a set into fixed number of subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541790/counting-ways-to-partition-a-set-into-fixed-number-of-subsets)).

---

The problem with counting injections from the other direction is that there are *many* ways to match a surjection to an injection. For example, $f\colon\{0,1\}\to\{0,1,2,3\}$ given by the identity will be the inverse of both $g(0)=g(2)=0; g(1)=g(3)=1$ as well $h(0)=h(2)=h(3)=0; h(1)=1$ and a couple of others. So you have to take this into account.

Comment: What you write is very convincing, but could you explain what is wrong in what I wrote?

Comment: You need to adjust for the fact there can be many surjection to inverse each injection.